# Can I use otf font in codename 1?

Tags: codenameone

Most of the fonts are OTF format, especially in Asia. Can I use the OTF format font in the cn1 theme? And the size of most OTF font files is more than 20MB. If I use 2 Asian OTF files in my project, the compiled file will be more than 50MB(codename1 limitation).

I have tried to convert OTF to TTF with online tools, but all of them failed to convert.

How do I use OTF font with codename1?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we don't have support for OTF fonts. The main challenge is passing this support through the full chain and all the supporting tools. As you indicated the size of a full unicode font is indeed a problem as well. For the case of TTF you can download the font after install and load it dynamically, although I understand this isn't an ideal situation and will severely hinder the development process.